# How can a remote server deploy a project without entering a password?

Tags: linux, git, deployment, secure-crt

The company is deploying it using the secure CRT(ssh) tool on a remote server.
The deploy procedure is as follows.

depoly.sh

```
   ↓
Move to tomcat directory.
   ↓
shutdown.sh
   ↓
startup.Sh
```

When using depoly.sh, the first of these, there is a problem that you can only run a command by entering a password.
I want it to run without entering the password.
Does anyone know a solution to this? Help me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+cache+password , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+password-less+push

Comment: Oh thank you! I don't know how to search for a solution, so I just asked. I'm sorry. I'll look carefully next time and ask questions. thank you very much haha.